# At least one operation is based on a WSDL message with a single part defined by a schema type, you should use a selector different than message body

Tags: osb

Am getting this warning during creation of proxy service.

> [OSB Kernel:398039] At least one operation is based on a WSDL message
>   with a single part defined by a schema type, you should use a selector
>   different than message body. Attempt to evaluate the operation, for
>   example during WS-Security,Operational Branch processing etc. - may
>   result in unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are creating a Proxy Service or Business Service using an unique wsdl, and different operations share some xsd elemennts.
(Two or more operations expect the same incoming message, you must use a selector different than message body)

Error Description:
There was a problem registering a WSDL-based service: the specified operation selection algorithm was SOAP Body while the associated WSDL binding was such that it is impossible to distinguish different operations based on data in the body of the incoming SOAP message.

Action:
Choose a different operation selection algorithm for the service or use a different WSDL binding.

Could you change the associated xsd?

Comment: Thanks Wanderley for answer, But I could not change the associated XSD.

Comment: Hey. Problem: It is likely that the schema type specified has multiple elements which is not recommended for the top level in SOAP. So you are using a 3rd party xsd? Since its a warning, couldnt you proceed?

Comment: Hey,I can proceed thats not a problem, I just want to know the reason of warning am getting.Thanks for your help.Could you please elaborate a little bit more the reason of warning.